# Running RemoteWebDriver Java Scripts Unlimted Times?

Tags: java, selenium, scripting, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am still a beginer with Java and anything to do with remotely doing anything. Please bear with me.

I am running a Java script that simulates the actions of a user on my companies site. They have asked me to use these scripts all day long. My question is, aside from TestingBot and Browserstack, who user an automated minute limiter, is there a service that I can use to perform a script over and over again through the day and night on a schedule that doesn't have a limit and that is free and remote?

I would run this scripts from my home at night and then again when I am at work. I live on a boat and the marina's internet is suspect at all times.

This may be a tough sell. But any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Scheduler may be helpful:
http://seleniumblog-sreenu.blogspot.in/2012/08/creating-scheduled-task-in-windows.html

Comment: I should have checked back in an hour ago when you posted this. I came across the same answer elsewhere on the net. Thank you good sir!